# Не запускается javascript в php-файле

Tags: php, javascript

index.html

```
<?php include "php/mail.php";?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Отправка форм AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Текст: </td><td><input type="text" name="text" required/>       </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Выражение: </td><td><input type="text" name="res" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $a. ' + ' .$b. ' = ';?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="res" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="отправить" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_POST['submit']){
if($_POST['res'] == $_SESSION['res']){
    $to = 'mail@mail.ru';
    $subject = 'Письмо с сайта';
    $body = $_POST['text'];
    $headers = 'Content-type:text/plain; Charset=windows-1251';

    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
        $_SESSION['mes'] = '<p>Письмо отправлено!</p>';
        header("Location: http://localhost:3000");
        exit();
    }else{
        $_SESSION['mes'] = '<p>Ошибка!</p>';
        header("Location: http://localhost:3000");
        exit();
    }
}else{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Вы ввели неверный логин или пароль.');
</script>";
    header("Location: http://localhost:3000");
    exit();
}
}

$a = rand(1,10);
$b = rand(1,10);
$_SESSION['res'] = $a + $b;
echo $_SESSION['mes'];
?>
```

Не запускается скрипт.

Comment: `alert('Вы ввели ,,,.');}` что за фигурная скобка в конце?

Comment: А что такое $_SESSION['res']? Где он?

Comment: Скобочка лишняя после alert. Ув. @Proshka, начинайте пользоваться консолью браузера, наверняка туда ошибка показалась.

Comment: `header('location: ..')` должен быть первым выводом на странице, если хотите куда то сделать редирект. У вас там нотис должен показываться, что заголовки уже отправлены.

Comment: @teran файл php подключен в начале страницы html, поэтому никаких нотисов нет

Comment: это они у вас отключены просто. Сообщение об ошибке `header()` должно показываться. И само по себе js на пустой странице, где кроме тэга `<script>` вообще ничего нет, работать не будет. У вас тут каша какая то из серверного и клиентского кода.

Comment: @Proshka `form method="post" action=" "` У тебя `action` пустой.

Comment: @teran эта каша специально заварена, чтобы разобраться как javascript интегрируется и работает в php

Comment: Советов много - решения нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ни как он не интегрируеться в php, по тому как php бэкэед а js фронтенд одним из способов передать сообщение на страницу записать в сессию

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_POST['submit']){
if($_POST['res'] == $_SESSION['res']){
    $to = 'mail@mail.ru';
    $subject = 'Письмо с сайта';
    $body = $_POST['text'];
    $headers = 'Content-type:text/plain; Charset=windows-1251';

    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
        $_SESSION['mes'] = 'Письмо отправлено!';
        header("Location: http://localhost:3000");
        exit();
    }else{
        $_SESSION['mes'] = 'Ошибка!';
        header("Location: http://localhost:3000");
        exit();
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['mes'] = 'Вы ввели неверный логин или пароль.';
    header("Location: http://localhost:3000");
    exit();
}
}

$a = rand(1,10);
$b = rand(1,10);
$_SESSION['res'] = $a + $b;
?>
```

и после вывести и стереть его из сессии

```
<?php include "php/mail.php";?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Отправка форм AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['mes'])): ?>
   <script>alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['mes'] ?>')</script>
   <?php $_SESSION['mes'] = null ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Текст: </td><td><input type="text" name="text" required/>       </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Выражение: </td><td><input type="text" name="res" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $a. ' + ' .$b. ' = ';?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="res" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="отправить" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Красиво и благородно! А главное - теперь понятна суть. Спасибо

Comment: А зачем тут $_SESSION['res'] ??

Comment: @ Michael $_SESSION['res'] - это массив сессионных переменных, в который в данном случае заносится значение суммы рандомных чисел для сравнения

Comment: @Michael судя по коду у автора это на подобие капчи.

Comment: Ну с сессией я знаком )) Я просто не понял для чего $_SESSION['res'] :)) Теперь вижу :)